# Upgrading to POI-3.16 from POI-3.9 for Excel Export

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When I replaced the JARs of POI-3.9 with POI-3.16, I am getting a popup

> We found a problem with some content in file.xlsx. Do you want us to
>   try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook, click Yes.

while opening the downloaded excel. After clicking Yes, I am getting another popup

> Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this
>   workbook may have been repaired or discarded.

But the contents are displayed properly after we click on OK. How can we avoid those popup alerts?

I have used theese JARs:

> 1. poi-3.16.jar
> 2. poi-ooxml-3.16.jar
> 3. poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar
> 4. xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
> 5. commons-codec-1.10.jar
> 6. commons-collections4-4.1.jar
> 7. commons-logging-1.2.jar
> 8. junit-4.12.jar
> 9. log4j-1.2.17.jar

Please suggest a proper solution.

Comment: i would say that depends on what exactly your code does

Comment: I agree with XtremeBaumer. You kind of have to remove functionality one-by-one until you find out which one won't work with the new version.

Comment: I have seen this dialog before in testing, and I am sure that there is a way to see what Excel changed. Or you could create a file with POI, make a copy, then open and save it with Excel, and see what the differences are. This will help us determine what is incorrect.

Comment: The usual suspects are multiple poi/xmlbeans versions in the classpath, older version of xerces/xalan, classloader issues with web containers. To verify 3.9 vs 3.16, you can unzip the .xlsx files and compare the xml content.

Comment: I tried to download blank excel sheet(using XSSFWorkbook) without any data but still getting the same issue.